# how to change width UITableViewCell and use in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, width

I have one class `ViewController` that I to create `TableView` in it with code not nib file and I want custom cell with `UITableViewCell` that has nib file.
I create TableView with code that has 320px width and I want create custom cell with `UITableViewCell` that my cells had 300px width and put in my TableView.

notice: I want these cells put center my table and these cells have 10px distance from two side!!!

this is my code:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    table = [self makeTableView];
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor: RGB(193,60,46)]; //will give a UIColor objct
    name = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
-(UITableView *)makeTableView
{
    CGFloat x = 0;
    CGFloat y = 0;
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    tableView.rowHeight = 60;
    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 22;
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 22;
    tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tableView.bounces = YES;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    return tableView;
}

#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObject) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLable.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

this is my code : [TableCode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8b5hp6x7qwy343y/TableCode.zip)

Comment: One way is to keep custom cell width as it is and start aligning the cell contents to start from 10px.

Comment: In your custom nib file keep the width of cell as same as UIViewController. Place all the contents of cell as required say start placing your UILabel at x = 10px, y = 0px and required width and height.

Comment: I so confused !!!! please tell me how to add UIView in UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a UITableView with a width of 685.

I created Custom UITableViewCell with a width of 685 also.

I have added two labels.

I aligned a label in such a way, the spacing for left and right are the same.

[image]

Comment: drag ang drop View from Object Library and set the Background to Clear color

Comment: My friend I do it but I have one question how to custom UIView draging to cell in CustomCell.m file???

Comment: drag it in the nib file then create the property. inside the implementation file, you can set the backgroundColor. Or even in the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: my friend I put my code in question please download my code and tell me where is it my mistake I so confused!!! :'(

Comment: are you sure you don't know how to add view in CustomCell? open CustomCell.xib file. Drag and drop View from Object Library. Create a property @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *customView; Inside CustomCell.m, add customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: I do it my friend please look my code...my problem here after add UIView to custom Cell when run my code I see my cell is 60px but my view is 50px!!! how to change height or width UIView in cell with code

Comment: implement heightForRowAtIndexPath:
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 50;
}

Answer (score 0):

afaik, cells are always the width of the table and you cant change that, you can fake it by making the content view of the cell transparent, then place another view with all your content in it that is a smaller width than the table

Comment: This is true, the width of the cells are hardcoded to match its parent, the UITableView. By default it's set to 320px.

Comment: my friend how to create fake content view of the cell transparent?

Comment: Override the method "- (void) layoutSubviews" in your CustomCell and make the  right view transparent by adding <yourView>.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].

Comment: mamal10, just add a UIView to your content view that is smaller than the content view, then set the background colour of the content view to clearColor